# How does Q-Learning deal with mixed strategies?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to understand how Q-learning deals with games where the optimal policy is a mixed strategy. The Bellman equation says that you should choose $max_a(Q(s,a))$ but this implies a single unique action for each $s$. Is Q-learning just not appropriate if you believe that the problem has a mixed strategy?

Comment: It's a basic concept in game theory. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Strategy_(game_theory)#/Pure_and_mixed_strategies
Essentially it's a strategy of sometimes choosing one action and sometimes choosing another in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use softmax and choose each action a randomly with probabiliy $p = \frac{\exp(Q(s,a))}{\sum_a \exp(Q(s,a))}$. I don't thinks it is still Q-learning though.